# Trigger event on slide change

Tags: owl-carousel

I am building a landing page with Owl Carousel.
I need the parent div's background image to change on every slide to a specific image and do the same when clicking the dots.
Have can this be achieved?

I have no idea how to trigger the event to change the background.

```
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            center: false,
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            margin: 10,
            autoWidth: false,
            nav: false,
            responsive: {
                600: {
                    items: 1
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

1. Automatically change the background image to another one.
2. Trigger the change when clicking on the dots.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks.
I already figured it out.
This is the code:

```
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            onTranslated: function(me) {
                $(me.target).find(".owl-item.active [data-src]:not(.loaded)").each(function(i, v) {
                    $(v).addClass("loaded").css("background-image", "url(" + $(v).attr("data-src") + ")");
                });
            },
            animateOut: 'zoomOut',
            animateIn: 'zoomIn',
            center: false,
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            margin: 10,
            autoWidth: false,
            nav: false,
            responsive: {
                600: {
                    items: 1
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();

// Listen to owl events:
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    // Trigger method goes here 
})
```

> **Owl Carousel Events Api** https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: From the @guy's answer, the correct option is ```onTranslated```
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this problem. I need to swipe only the content and image of each content automatically must be shown on mobile devices. Hassan's comment helped me.

owl.carousel *changed* event returns some objects. I used **page.index** object to define the index of active slide.

The index of first slide is **0**. Therefore, I named the images like img0, img1, img2 ...

```
     var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
     owl.owlCarousel(); 

     owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
       //$(this) refers to active content
       //SELECT img TAG TO CHANGE THE src ATTRIBUTE
       $(this).parents('.img-parent')
              .find('img') 
              .attr('src',`img${e.page.index}.svg`)
     })
```

Comment: Glad my answer help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this problem. I wanted to find an event after the shift was completed.
The translated.owl.carousel event is perfect but it has one disadvantage, if you rotate the smartphone screen the event is triggered without changing the slide. Probably in skewed refreshment due to slider width change.

```
  var current_slide_id = getActualLessonId(); // my custom parametr
  learing_slider.on('translated.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    if (current_slide_id != getActualLessonId()) {
      // todo after change
    }
    current_slide_id = getActualLessonId();
  });
```